# VSCode Explorer always excludes files in .gitignore

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore

Using VS Code 1.74.2, any files or folders in .gitignore are excluded from the File Explorer tree. None of the solutions seen on the web work...

```
"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": false, doesn't work
files: exclude doesn't work
```

Isn't .gitignore meant to indicate files and folders you don't want in the repository? If yes, then why does it also remove them from the VS Code file explorer. What can I do to stop files and folders going into the repository but still have them visible in the File Explorer tree?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear from your question but are the files you want to see NOT in the `Files: Exclude` setting?

Comment: 1) I put the line */Generated Scripts*/ into .gitignore with no entry in sttings.json. The folders disappear from the explorer tree

Comment: 2) The lines     "files.exclude": {
        "**/Generated Scripts*": false,
      }, are put into settings.json with no entry in gitignore. The tree obeys the true/false setting.

Comment: 3) the line is put into gitignore and the setting into settings.json. The true/false has no effect and the folders do not appear in the tree

Comment: If present in the settings file "explorer.excludeGitIgnore": false, has no effect whether it's true or false. The examples 1,2 & 3 apply regardless of the prescence and setting of this line. I hope this clarifies. Looking at GitHub this was a "bug" but has been fixed. Hence asking if it's me and there's a combination I'm just not getting.